# Visual Studio 2012 Order Unit Tests Ran

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way in visual studio 2012 to find out the order unit tests were ran?

Comment: If it's relevant, there's something wrong with your tests. Unit tests generally should not be written dependent on order, or the success/failure of another test.

Comment: [Here](http://www.amazon.com/The-Art-Unit-Testing-Examples/dp/1933988274 "The Art of Unit Testing") is a good reference that I'd recommend.

Comment: We have attempted to write them non-dependent of order, but for some reason some tests are breaking only when a run all is performed.  So I am looking to see what order visual studio has ran the tests in order to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Look into this link: http://xunitpatterns.com/Erratic%20Test.html. There's a lot of useful stuff there about when tests fail in some cases but not others.

Answer (score 1):

You can create ordered tests e.g.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

but as @flynn1179 pointed out, that is a very bad smell indeed. Unit tests should not depend on the order they run. Unit tests need to be isolated from each other, else you will have a major PITA on your hands, and ultimately the tests may get neglected, or new tests may not get added due to the hassle.

EDIT:

OK, based on your feedback - the test that is failing, what is the error message, or assertion failure? With the failing test, look to see if there is any shared objects, or resources. There must be something about that test which is being shared across the test suite.

Can you post the code to the failing test, we might be able to assist more.

Comment: I am not interested in ordered tests at the moment.